# textField beginEditing is called multiple times , can't trace out the issue

Tags: ios, swift2, uitextfield

i have a textField where i putted a pickerView to appear when the editing begins when the Picker appears am triggering a alertView with a textFeld in it with two buttons and when this alertView appears my main textfield ends Editing : but when am hitting any of the buttons of my AlertView the main textfield is begins editing , i am trying to figure out why this happening from hours but didnt get any clue yet below is my code (only portion which  thought really responsible for my problem  ) :

```
class ProfileSettingTableViewController: UITableViewController,   UITextFieldDelegate  {


@IBOutlet var myextField: UITextField! // my main textField

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    myTextField.delegate = self
    tableView.tableFooterView = nil
    tableView.tableHeaderView = nil

}

// the below function being called once i trigger a button from the picker 

func showPickerViewAfterTextFieldEditingEnds {

        var tField: UITextField!

        func configurationTextField(textField: UITextField!)
        {
            textField.placeholder = "Enter here"
            tField = textField
        }


        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Your Name", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {

            UIAlertAction in
            self.myTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            print("close button tapped")

        }

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(configurationTextField)  

 // my below added  functions (in the alert) is forcing my textField to start editing in odds attempts (when i hit the button  first time then on third time then on 5th time and so on)


        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

            self.myTextField.text = ""
            self.myTextField.text = tField.text
            self.myTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        })
    }

}

 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField){

    let leftbutton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
    let rightbutton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftbutton
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightbutton

}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField){

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func nameEditingFinished(sender: AnyObject) {





}

@IBAction func selectNamePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

  // my picker function which activates it self when the main TextField is begins editing... and from here the AlertView appears..

}

}
```

if anybody gets any clue than please let me know it'll be so helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this is happening looking at this portion of the code, but it seems that you're trying to use a pickerView as the input view for the textField. If so, there are easier ways to do it than using beginsEditing. For example, you could do something like the following:

```
    self.picker = UIPickerView()
    textfield.inputView = picker
    textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldEndEditing), forControlEvents: .EditingDidEnd)
    picker.dataSource = self
    picker.delegate = self


func textFieldEndEditing(textField : UITextField) {
    //Do whatever you would like the callback to do, like:
    let row = self.picker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    let value = pickerView(self.picker, titleForRow: row, forComponent: 0)
    textField.text = value

}
```